# I'm trying to prevent the execution of a command in BASH.. Doesn't work always

Tags: linux, bash

This is based on [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638367/shopt-s-extdebug-in-bashrc-not-working-in-script-files). I am trying to prevent executions of certain commands using a script. I got the script to work perfectly in interactive shells, but for noninteractive shells it doesn't prevent its execution.

/home/user/stop.sh (sourced in .bashrc)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extdebug; stop_cmd () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # not needed for completion
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # not needed for prompt
    local this_command=$BASH_COMMAND;
    echo $this_command" Not Allowed";
    return 1
};
trap 'stop_cmd' DEBUG
```

/home/user/temp.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls
```

I used the BASH_ENV variable suggested by [@Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) to get my script into script files that use non-interactive shells.

In a new shell

```
#:export BASH_ENV=/home/user/stop.sh
#:ls
ls Not Allowed --> This is because of the source in .bashrc
#:             --> Prompt appears. ls did not run
#:./temp.sh
./temp.sh: /usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc: No such file or directory
./temp.sh: warning: cannot start debugger; debugging mode disabled
ls Not Allowed  --> Because of the $BASH_ENV
Directory contents displayed  --> ls ended up running
#:             --> Prompt appears after executing temp.sh
```

But this behavior is not displayed if I `source stop.sh` within `temp.sh` directly and it works like a charm.

Comment: I did not do it! But can you explain how are you using `BASH_ENV` in your code above? and contents of the file passed to it

Comment: @Inian Sorry if it isn’t apparent.. let me edit the question. and I know you didn’t do it 

Comment: @Inian Done editing the question

Comment: Griping about downvotes is a great way to attract more of them. This is not how it's properly supposed to work but unremarkable given the situation where you are asking for help and are still apparently learning the rules of this site.

Comment: As an aside, `echo $this_command" Not Allowed";` looks odd. There is no particular reason to put the static string inside double quotes, but lots of reasons to have `$this_command` inside quotes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: @tripleee I apologize about that.. I'm just splitting my hair on why a source inside the script behaves so differently from $BASH_ENV

Comment: It looks like it loses the value of the `DEBUG` trap but it's still not clear where exactly this is happening or why the trap gets set to a file name which cannot be found, or where that file name is controlled. I think you need `set -T` but I don't know enough about `DEBUG` traps to really look properly into this.

Comment: @tripleee By losing value.. you mean the return 1 value right? Or are you saying the trap isn't being invoked for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164733/discussion-between-sam-thomas-and-tripleee).

Comment: I haven't tried to repro but it's looking like `trap 'stop_cmd' DEBUG` is not getting inherited.  I'm speculating that `env` is the culprit here.

Comment: Can you update the question to state that you're aware that this will be trivial to circumvent? This will help future readers who come across it.

Comment: Well?  Any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Chet Ramey, `shopt -s extdebug` is internally equally to `— debugger`. And if bash doesn’t find a debugger during its initialization it unsets this option essentially making my `return 1` useless. The above said only happens in non interactive mode since interactive shells can’t be debugged (hence the flags are not unset). And this explains clearly the behaviors stated in my question. So in scripts that should use my trap would need to reset  `shopt - s extdebug` at the very top.

Answer (score 1):

1. The simplest way to prevent users from running any command
   is to not give them accounts. 
   (You say you want to “prevent executions of certain commands”,
   but your `stop.sh` prevents all commands. 
   This makes your question somewhat hard to understand.)
2. The simplest way to prevent users from running certain programs
   is to chmod them to 700. 
   If designated users are required to be able to run the program,
   give them access with ACLs. 
   (If only a few users are required to be blocked,
   you may be able to do that with ACLs, but that might be unreliable.)

   Your approach is going to be very hard to get right. 
   Assuming that you really want to prevent people from running `ls` (really?),
   do you plan on handling things like

   ```
   cp /bin/ls ls_copy
   ./ls_copy
   ```

   or

   ```
   ln -s /bin/ls ls_link
   ./ls_link
   ```

   ?
3. I learned today that bash has a debug mode. 
   I don’t know much about it, but I’ve discovered experimentally that,
   when a bash process starts and reads a BASH_ENV file that sets `extdebug`,
   it (the bash shell) tries to read `/usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc`. 
   (This path, apparently, is hard-coded in `/bin/bash`.) 
   This should come as no surprise to you,
   as you got an error message naming that file. 
   Evidently there was a problem reading that file.

   This does not happen if you set `extdebug`
   and/or do `trap some_command DEBUG`
   in the script (directly or via `source`); I don’t know why. 
   ([Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/bashdb/discussion/206896/thread/883f6397) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=9296) are a couple of references
   about the bash debugger.)

   Suggestions:

   - If the `/usr/share/bashdb` directory doesn’t exist,
     or it does but the `bashdb-main.inc` file doesn’t exist,
     create them (empty file).
   - If `/usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc` exists,
     rename it to a backup name. 
     In particular, this will be useful
     if `bashdb-main.inc` is a symbolic link to a file that doesn’t exist.
   - If `/usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc` exists,
     and you try the second bullet above (rename the file)
     and that doesn’t work, try the first bullet (create an empty file).
4. By doing the above (renaming `/usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc`),
   I was able to get your command-execution-prevention trick working.

Comment: Hi @G-Man, I was working on this and spoke to Chet Ramey along the way and hence it took a while. Sorry about the late reply.  1 (my code is just an example) and 2 does not serve my purpose since I wish to prevent cases where the command is allowed to be used but not certain Params passed to that command. Eg: ls is allowed but not ls -al. Let’s get down to your suggestion on 3. That file is used by the package bashdb and doing it your way prevents a person from actually using bashdb. Also when bashdb is in place all the traps are removed.

Comment: If the traps are removed it’s absolutely fine with me since they won’t be able to debug my trap ! Haha